# How to Fix Error in the Metadata manager while deploying a Cube with Time Dimension [The 'Date' discretized attribute cannot have related attributes]

Tags: ssas

I am on learning stage of SSAS and following a Book on this. Trying to Deploy a simple cube with Time dimension by picking DimDate table from adventureworksDw database and getting the following Error :
Errors in the metadata manager. The 'Date' discretized attribute cannot have related attributes

NA

Code can't be provided as it is a simple Cube using Dimdate Table.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you tried mixing discretization and attribute relationships. I would remove the discretization by changing the DiscretizationBucketCount and DiscretizationMethod properties. [This article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3155/sql-server-analysis-services-discretization/) explains these settings and provides some screenshots of how discretization works.